# Is there any way to show the data from sqlite3 for scroll down options by using html?

Tags: python, html, sqlite

I created a sqlite3 database which has a table to store some data(table includes time, day, weather...etc. options). And ideally, I'd like to use scroll down selection way to show these data on web and let user to choose the specific time to see the result. Is there any way I can to that?

[image]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: That's a whole app. Attempt to write one and check back in if you run into a specific problem. Start by choosing a framework, e.g. Django or Flask.